Why are the number of parameters not decreasing after pruning?
I have created a traditional neural network in Python using Keras. My goal is to train and test the model. Then, I would like to prune, train, and test the pruned model. I wish to compare the performance of the two models. However, when I implemented magnitude-based weight pruning, the model summary shows that the number of parameters has increased. Indeed, when I train and test the pruned model, it takes slightly more time and gives the same accuracy. The expected result is the opposite: less time with less accuracy.
I am building this for PA behavioral modeling. Below is the code:
import os

os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'

import tf_keras as keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
import tempfile
import time

# Load input data
data_input = pd.read_csv('Input_TimeAligned.csv',header = None)
data_input.columns = ['i','q']
data_input.describe()
data_input.head()

# Convert input data to an array
data_input_arr = data_input.to_numpy()
print('Input data as an array:',data_input_arr)
print(len(data_input_arr))
print()

# Load output data
data_output = pd.read_csv('Output_TimeAligned.csv',header = None)
data_output.columns = ['i','q']
data_output.describe()
data_output.head()

# Convert output data to an array
data_output_arr = data_output.to_numpy()
print('Output data as an array:',data_output_arr)
print(len(data_output_arr))
print()

# Create test-train splits (25% train, 75% test)
data_input_tr = data_input_arr[0:122879,:]
data_output_tr = data_output_arr[0:122879,:]

data_input_test = data_input_arr[122880:491519,:]
data_output_test = data_output_arr[122880:491519,:]

X_train = data_input_tr
y_train = data_output_tr

X_test = data_input_test
y_test = data_output_test

# Define the unpruned model architecture.
start = time.time()
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (2,)),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer_1'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 256, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer_2'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 512, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer_3'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 256, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer_4'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer_5'),
  keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation = 'tanh', name = 'output_layer'),
])

# Compile the unpruned model
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['Accuracy'])
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to compile the model is:', end - start)
print()

print(model.summary()) # Unpruned model summary
print()

# Train unpruned model
start = time.time()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32)    
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to train the model is:', end - start)
print()

# Test and evaluate unpruned model
start = time.time()
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to test the model is:', end - start)
print('The predicted output is:', y_hat)
print()

start = time.time()
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to evaluate the model is:', end - start)
print()

## Pruning
prune_low_magnitude = tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude

pruning_params = {
    'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.ConstantSparsity(target_sparsity=0.5,
                                                              begin_step=0,
                                                              frequency=100000)
}

## This is another weight pruning technique I found on the official tutorial page
# # Define model for pruning.
# pruning_params = {
#       'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.0,
#                                                                final_sparsity=0.80,
#                                                                begin_step=0,
#                                                                end_step=1000)
# }

model_for_pruning = prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

# `prune_low_magnitude` requires a recompile.
start = time.time()
model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['Accuracy'])
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to compile the second pruned model is:', end - start)
print()

######### Pruned model summary
model_for_pruning.summary() 

logdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

callbacks = [
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep(),
  tfmot.sparsity.keras.PruningSummaries(log_dir=logdir),
]

# Pruned model training
start = time.time()
model_for_pruning.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train, 
    epochs=5, 
    batch_size=32, 
    callbacks= callbacks
)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to train the pruned model is:', end - start)

# Pruned model testing and evaluation
start = time.time()
y_hat = model_for_pruning.predict(X_test)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to test the pruned model is:', end - start)
print('The predicted output is:', y_hat)
print()

start = time.time()
model_for_pruning.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
end = time.time()
print('Time taken to evaluate the pruned model is:', end - start)
print()

Below is the model summary for the unpruned model:
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 layer_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               384

 layer_2 (Dense)             (None, 256)               33024

 layer_3 (Dense)             (None, 512)               131584

 layer_4 (Dense)             (None, 256)               131328

 layer_5 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896

 output_layer (Dense)        (None, 2)                 258       

=================================================================
Total params: 329474 (1.26 MB)
Trainable params: 329474 (1.26 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
None

And this is the model summary for the "pruned" model:
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 prune_low_magnitude_layer_  (None, 128)               642
 1 (PruneLowMagnitude)

 prune_low_magnitude_layer_  (None, 256)               65794
 2 (PruneLowMagnitude)

 prune_low_magnitude_layer_  (None, 512)               262658
 3 (PruneLowMagnitude)

 prune_low_magnitude_layer_  (None, 256)               262402
 4 (PruneLowMagnitude)

 prune_low_magnitude_layer_  (None, 128)               65666
 5 (PruneLowMagnitude)

 prune_low_magnitude_output  (None, 2)                 516
 _layer (PruneLowMagnitude)

=================================================================
Total params: 657678 (2.51 MB)
Trainable params: 329474 (1.26 MB)
Non-trainable params: 328204 (1.25 MB)
_________________________________________________________________

The parameters and the storage sizes have increased.
I recently found out that a similar pruning approach in PyTorch just applies a mask on the network to effectively zero out the low-magnitude weights. Is something like that happening in Keras, or am I missing something? If it is true, then how can I actually 'prune' to get a trainable and testable pruned network?
